# Typescript json formation through arrays

Tags: typescript

my json object structure should be

```
customers: [{
  customer: [
    { key: 'customername', value: 'xxxx' },
    { key: 'address', value: 'xxxxxx' }
  ]}, {
    customer: [
      { key: 'customername', value: 'yyyyy' },
      { key: 'address', value: 'xxxxxxxxxx' }
  ]}]
```

from backend i getting data as below

```js
const customerArray = [];
for(let content of customers[i].customer)
  {
    const customervalue = [];
    let customername = { key: "customername", value: content.customername };
    let dataItemUserId = {key: "address", value: content.address}
       
    customervalue.push(customername); 
    customervalue.push(address);
       
    customerArray.push(customervalue);             
  }  
processDataContent['customers']= dataEntryArray;
```

I am unable to get a way how can i make the element "customer"?? i believe i need to modify the way how i push to customer array i.e. in the line  customerArray.push(customervalue);

any leads??
P.S. New to typescript so might be missing something very basic

Comment: what is ur input and what kind of output you want in terms of json?

Comment: customerset has customer object

Comment: {customerid: "11234", customername: "#####", address: "XXXX"}
{customerid: "1111", customername: "#####", address: "XXXX"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why you are storing data like this..
As per you inputs and output expected. below simple code fulfil your requirements.

```js
const customers = [ {customerid: "11234", customername: "#####", address: "XXXX"},
{customerid: "1111", customername: "#####", address: "XXXX"}
];


let customerArray = [];

for(let customer of customers)
{
 const customervalue = [
    { key: "customername", value: customer.customername },
    {key: "address", value: customer.address}
    ];
    customerArray = [...customerArray, { customer: customervalue }];  

}  


const processDataContent = {
 customers: customerArray
}

console.log(processDataContent);
```

Comment: Thank you.. i was looking for below syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incredibly vague, but I'm inclined to believe that you're somewhat confused by how you should approach Typescript.
Maybe this might help:

```
interface ICustomer {
    customer: { key: string, value: string }[]
}

function GetCustomers(): ICustomer[] {
    let customers: ICustomer[] = [];
    for(let content of customers)
    {
        customers.push({
            customer: [
                { key: 'customername', value: 'Stanislas' },
                { key: 'address', value: 'Belgium' }
            ]
        });
    }
    return customers;
}
```

You can also run it in the [typescript sandbox](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ICustomer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20customer%3A%20%7B%20key%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20string%20%7D%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20GetCustomers()%3A%20ICustomer%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20customers%3A%20ICustomer%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20content%20of%20customers)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20customers.push(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20customer%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20'customername'%2C%20value%3A%20'Stanislas'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20'address'%2C%20value%3A%20'Belgium'%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20customers%3B%0D%0A%7D) to see what the javascript output will be.

The whole point of using Typescript is to define types.
In this case, simply by defining an ICustomer, your code should become a lot more readable.

---

Note: If you have any control over the JSON, I would recommend to make it more readable, by using this format:

```
interface ICustomer {
    customerName: string,
    address: string
}

function GetCustomers(): ICustomer[] {
    let customers: ICustomer[] = [];
    for(let content of customers)
    {
        customers.push({
            customerName: 'Stanislas',
            address: 'Belgium'
        });
    }
    return customers;
}
```